# TSQL display field values for column with count column in condition

Tags: sql-server, count

I have query which will group column 1 and 2  and calculate count for column3

```
(select col1, col2, count(col3)
from table1
group by col1,col2
Having count(col3) < 50)
```

But I want to display all fields values for col3 where count(col3) < 50 . Can you help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, t.cnt 
from (
  select col1, col2, col3, 
         count(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) AS cnt
  from table1 ) as t
where t.cnt < 50
```

The idea is to use windowed version of `COUNT` instead of `GROUP BY`. `COUNT(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2)` returns the count of `col3` occurrences per `col1, col2` *for every row* of `table1`. You can filter out `col1, col2` slices having a count of 50 or more in an outer query.

Comment: worked great!  Thank you, I was surprised for really quick answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from table1 t
where
EXITS(select 1 from table1 t1 where t.col1 = t1.col1 and t.col2 = t.col2 having count(t1.col3) > 50)
```

or something like this:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from table1 t
inner join (select t1.col1, t1.col2, count(t1.col3) from table1 t1 
group by t1.col1, t1.col2 having count(t1.col3) > 50) x
on t.col1 = x.col1 and t.col2 = x.col2
```

Comment: This solution also worked after I made some small changes. Thank you. Guys you are really perfect.